# Why can't jenkins connect to my S3 service?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-s3

Jenkins: Version: 2.7.2
Amazon Web Services SDK - 1.10.50

I set up an s3bucket lets say it's named *johnnybravo*
I created an IAM user, downloaded it's credentials and then added the following inline policy to it as suggested by https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/S3+Plugin:

```
{
"Statement": [
    {
        "Action": [
            "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
    },
    {
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::johnnybravo",
            "arn:aws:s3:::johnnybravo/*"
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Then in jenkins I added an amazon s3 profile named jenkinsS3
Put in the access key and secret key I downloaded earlier when creating the iam user. Got a check succesfull by jenkins. I did not select the "Use IAM Role" checkbox due to an issue: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-36430

In the build itself I point to the jenkinsS3 profile from the earlier config I did. On the build itself it fails on the publishing to S3 due to the following reason:

```
com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain
at com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProviderChain.getCredentials(AWSCredentialsProviderChain.java:131)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3653)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.initiateMultipartUpload(AmazonS3Client.java:2651)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.UploadCallable.initiateMultipartUpload(UploadCallable.java:350)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.UploadCallable.uploadInParts(UploadCallable.java:178)
```

Does anyone know of a way if I can find out if the problem is with the credentials or if it's the plugin that's acting up?

Maybe I should downgrade the s3plugins version but I don't know to which version.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Jenkins log:

```
Launching slave agent (via Trilead SSH2 Connection): java  -jar /tmp/slave.jar
Aug 31, 2016 1:48:24 PM WARNING org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog warn
Error while serving http://10.0.10.100:8080/publisher/S3BucketPublisher/loginCheck
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:324)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:167)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:100)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:124)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:746)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:876)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$5.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:233)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:746)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:876)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:649)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:238)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:812)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:135)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
    at hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:51)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at jenkins.security.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:117)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:142)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at jenkins.security.BasicHeaderProcessor.doFilter(BasicHeaderProcessor.java:93)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
    at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:67)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:76)
    at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:553)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544)
    at winstone.BoundedExecutorService$1.run(BoundedExecutorService.java:77)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain
    at com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProviderChain.getCredentials(AWSCredentialsProviderChain.java:131)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3653)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3612)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.listBuckets(AmazonS3Client.java:743)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.listBuckets(AmazonS3Client.java:749)
    at hudson.plugins.s3.S3BucketPublisher$DescriptorImpl.doLoginCheck(S3BucketPublisher.java:385)
    ... 68 more
```

Comment: It doesn't sound like a credentials problem because Jenkins isn't even able to successfully find credentials per the error message. Anything useful in the Jenkins log?

Comment: No :/ just: Error while serving http://10.0.10.100:8080/publisher/S3BucketPublisher/loginCheck
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)... (Ill update the OP)